# No video playback or no sound after launching a game (Minecraft)

Tags: arch-linux, audio, nvidia, pulseaudio

#### Situation

I played a little around with Minecraft mods and wanted to do some modding myself. And since Linux runs Minecraft a lot faster on my machine (with the proprietary nVidia driver), why not program on Linux. Also i like the developer tools on Linux much better.

So i installed the driver on my Machine:
**Machine:**

- Ryzen 3800X
- GTX 1060 3GB OC (Driver: 515.48.07)

**Linux:**

- Arch Linux (Kernel 5.18.6)
- gnome-shell (42.2-1)
- Minecraft Launcher (1.0.1221)
- Pulseaudio (16.1.1)

#### Problem

I watch some videos on the topic of modding and after Minecraft launches and gets to the title screen, a few things start to break.

What I discovered:

- Firefox/Librewolf refuses to playback youtube videos

  - it starts a few milliseconds of the videos and then stops
  - it's not a network problem
  - it buffers the video like it normally would
- VLC media player behaves weirdly

  - no sound
  - the actual video is played in a second window, the main VLC window is empty but contains the playback bar
- Spotify cannot playback music

  - one time it playes music but there is no sound output (in general)
  - sometimes it errors: Something went wrong

There are a view differences with each try:

- a few times it kept the audio output to `line-out`, as I configured it, but still didn't output any audio
- most recently starting Minecraft changed the audio output to my HDMI monitor

  - setting the output back to `line-out` manually kept me from hearing anything
  - I was able to hear Minecraft audio after that

#### What I tried

A logout/login resets everything: Sound works until I run Minecraft. I suspect the pulseaudio-daemon gets restarted.
I have no idea how to start, what logs to view or if I need to install any additional software for audio to work.

In addition, I launched the above programs from a terminal, there was no unusual output or error messages.

Comment: "GTX 1060 3GB OC (Driver: 5.15.48.07)" : I understand you want nvidia proprietary drivers. Then why do you show what seems to be a kernel version ? Using nouveau instead ?

Comment: Typo, a dot got mixed in there

Comment: Like i said, the game runs a lot faster with the proprietary driver (35 FPS [40 with render optimization] compared to 150 FPS [over 600])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using PipeWire instead of PulseAudio and see if it resolves the audio issue.

sudo pacman -S pipewire pipewire-pulse wireplumber xdg-desktop-portal-gnome

systemctl --user enable wireplumber.service pipewire.service pipewire-pulse.service

It should automatically remove and replace PulseAudio.
If it does not remove it because of dependencies then first run: sudo pacman -Rdd PulseAudio

Comment: I already resolved this issue but it's the right solution.